# How do I create a content node based on different conditions, using xsl:if-else?

Tags: xml, xslt

Right now, I'm creating the following node based off the text of the headerListImport div.

```
<content name="importBizPartner">
  <xsl:value-of select="//div[@class='headerListImport']/a/text()" />
</content>
```

The problem is sometimes the text node is empty.  In that case, I want to the contents of the node to be 'No Name Available'.

I know, I  *should*  know how to do this, but I'm drawing a blank.  My application allows me to use xsl:if-else, but I'm not sure of the sytax.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go with `xsl:choose`, as XSLT doesn't have a `xsl:if-else` element:

```
<content name="importBizPartner">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(//div[@class='headerListImport']/a/text())">
            <xsl:value-of select="//div[@class='headerListImport']/a/text()" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            No data available
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</content>
```